# Bound $E( (X - E X) (Y- E Y)^2)$ tighter than via CS

Tags: probability, inequality, expected-value, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Given X, Y dependent, bounded random variables: $-1\leq X\leq 1$ and $0\leq Y\leq 1$. Via Cauchy Schwarz $E( (X - E X) (Y- E Y)^2 )\leq \sqrt{ {\rm Var}(X)  E(Y-E Y)^4}$ and with $E(Y-E Y)^4 = {\rm Var}(Y-EY)^2 + {\rm Var}^2(Y) \leq {\rm Var}(Y) + {\rm Var}^2(Y) $ I can bound everything in terms of second moments:
$E( (X - E X) (Y- E Y)^2 )\leq \sqrt{ {\rm Var}(X)\left({\rm Var}(Y) + {\rm Var}^2(Y) \right) }$
but the bounding ${\rm Var}(Y-EY)^2 \leq {\rm Var}(Y) $ is to loose, respectively on $E(Y-E Y)^4$,  and I cannot compute directly higher moments. Is there another bounding of $E( (X - E X) (Y- E Y)^2 )$?

Edit:

E.g. can one show somthing like $E( (X - E X) (Y- E Y)^2 ) \leq \sqrt{{\rm Var}(X) {\rm Var^2}(Y) }$

Comment: OK, I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do better than with $\sqrt{Var[X]Var[(Y-E(Y))^2]}$ on the RHS. Consider $1-2p$ probability to have $(-1,1/2)$, $p$ probability to have $(1,0)$, $p$ probability to have $(1,1)$. Then $E((X-E(X))(Y-E(Y))^2)=p(1-2p)$. On the other hand $Var(X)=8p(1-2p)$ and $Var[(Y-E(Y))^2]=p(1-2p)/8$ This achieves the inequality. While $Var^2(Y)=p^2/4$, this does not suffice to prove when $p$ is close to zero.

On the other hand, since $X-E(X)$ has mean zero, we can write $E((X-E(X))((Y-E(Y))^2))=E[(X-E[X])((Y-E[Y])^2-E[(Y-E[Y])^2])]$, which can have this $\sqrt{Var[X]Var[(Y-E(Y))^2]}$ upper bound.

Comment: I would be even happy with $\sqrt{Var(X) Var^2(Y)}$ but I get sth more like $\sqrt{Var(X) Var(Y)}$

Comment: @user18722294 In your post you are having some result of $\sqrt{Var(X)Var^2(Y)}$ correct...? Or if I have understand wrong...?

Comment: I have $\sqrt{Var(X) (Var(Y) + Var^2(Y))}$, I added the total formula. So I would be happy to get rid of $Var(Y)$

Comment: @user18722294 Oh the display on my mobile is misleading me. I saw something like $E(Y-E Y)^4 = {\rm Var}(Y-EY)^2$ I can $ + {\rm Var}^2(Y) \leq {\rm Var}(Y) + {\rm Var}^2(Y)
$. The ''I can'' Split the formula into two halves weirdly. I thought you have $E(Y-E Y)^4 = {\rm Var}(Y-EY)^2$ And just wonder how you get this.

Comment: My problem is that  I cannot calculate ${\rm Var}(Y-EY)^2$ and ${\rm Var}(Y-EY)^2 \leq {\rm Var}(Y) $ is to loose, do you know a bounding of this quantity in terms of $Var^2(Y)$?

Comment: @user18722294 It's impossible to bounded by $Var(Y)^2$. See the updated answer. Also, $(Y-E(Y)^2)$ is inside the $Y$. And I don't think you can claim that ${\rm Var}[(Y-EY)^2] \leq C{\rm Var}(Y)^2$ for any $C$.